# WooCommerce shopping cart loading after adding an item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

We have a problem with loading of cart contents in the shopping cart icon.

If there are 0 items, the shoppng cart display 0. When you add an item, the shopping cart will have a load icon spinning. If I manualy go to /winkelmand (shopping cart in dutch) it will show me the items I have in there and allow me to checkout. If I remove the item when I go there manualy, the shopping cart will display 0 again.

I haven't changed anything about the shopping cart.

Comment: If you post a link to the site if possible that should help people see the problem. Also what theme are you using and do you have any caching plugins installed?

Comment: We use the Porto theme. [Here](https://www.meprint.nl/reclameborden-en-panelen/) is a direct link to the form you have to fill out before you can add it to the shopping cart. We use the W3 Total Cache plugin.

Comment: My first thoughts would be the issue is related to the W3 Total Cache plugin but its supported by the theme so unless you have made changes to the theme files it probably isn't. I'm having a bit of trouble adding items to the cart due to everything being in dutch

Comment: Basically you have to select an option and go down. If you just select the first option every time you should be able to get through. Then you have to upload an image and then you can continue (Volgende is how it's called).